# How to deal with secrets in app.yaml and not putting it in GIT?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, gcloud

Google Cloud Platform doesn't describe how to deal with environmental variables in your `app.yaml`.

Starting up with GCP and Google App Engine, I read about setting my config variables in `app.yaml` which makes sense in a way, but I don't want to put my password/secrets/keys/etc in my GIT repository.

Presuming that @Google's engineers are smart enough to not want this either, I'd guess that the best practise would be to put `app.yaml` in `.gitignore`.

Executing `gcloud app deploy` results in a perfectly working app. But it still it remains an unfinished issue to me and I strongly believe there should be a article somewhere that describes what the best practise is.

Can someone confirm that:

1. putting `app.yaml` in `.gitignore`, and then,
2. set my secrets in `app.yaml`, and then,
3. performing `gcloud app deploy`

is the way to go?

Comment: Have you looked at the document here?
https://cloud.google.com/ruby/rails/appengine#deploy-to-app-engine

Comment: Hey @PawelCzuczwara you are right. I posted a detailed answer.

Comment: Hi @PawelCzuczwara and @demir, thanks for your answers, but this is exact the document that got me stuck and the cause to ask this question. It explains in detail how to setup `app.yaml` but t doesn't explain how to cope with secrets in relation to version managament

Answer (score 2):

You should use rails environment variables.

**Before Rails 5.2**

You can use [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv)

**With Rails 5.2**

You can use both **dotenv** and **rails credentials**.

**With rails credentials:**

1. Add `secret_key_base` variable to the **credentials** file.
2. Use `secret_key_base` variable in the **app.yaml** file:

   ```
   env_variables:

     SECRET_KEY_BASE: <% = Rails.application.credentials[:secret_key_base] %>
   ```

[Google's configuration document](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/rails/appengine#deploy-to-app-engine)

[Rails credentials](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#custom-credentials)

**EDIT**

[Adding and updating environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/environment-variables#adding_and_updating_environment_variables) for Google Cloud Platform

Comment: This indeed is a solution that works. However, the article doesn't mention anything about security (e.g. putting `app.yaml` in `.gitignore` to prevent the secret being pushed into version control), and this is what confuses me.

Perfoming `gcloud app deploy` publishes the `ENV` variables literally in the deploy logs. It is hard to believe this is a best practise since all passwords and secrets are published at that moment.

At other PAAS services such as Heroku have the opportunity to enter the `ENV` variables manually and therefore preventing to putting your secrets all over the internet.

Comment: Google Cloud Platform is [secured on many layers](https://cloud.google.com/security/), so I do not understand in what situation it could be your concern?.

Comment: If you push your `app.yaml` to your version control, than your secrets are publicly available. One could say: then don't publish them (e.g by putting `app.yaml` in `.gitignore`) but then still the logs created while deploying the app publish the secrets.

Comment: @double_u1 I've added a link to the related document. Can you check the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you rather than put your config to `app.yaml` file to use something like config server [spring boot example](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html), that you'll easy setup to fetch you config parameters from git, or database or vault(for sensitive data). Also you could consider store you parameters in `appengine memcache` on in some storage like `datastore`.

For now in our project we're just appending `app.yaml` with `env_variables` section in one of our pipeline's steps before deploying. Using `Teamcity` for build, `Vault` for storing secrets. `Teamcity` has build in `Vault` integration. But I'd like to change it to use config server in nearest future.

Comment: Thanks, this is a really nice solution! Still I'm surprised that Google doesn't seem to have a solution for this.